# Different version of chatGPT for portfolio-chatbot

Tags: javascript, express, chatbot, chatgpt-api

I'm working on my portfolio and would like to implement a version of chatGPT to it so the potential employer can get information about me by chatting with my chatbot. I'm using express.js for the fetching. As for now, my chatbot uses davinci as the engine but i would prefer to use GPT 3.5, but somehow when i change the engine from text-davinci-003 to gpt-3.5-turbo-0613 in the url, i get an error object logged to the console and i cannot figure out why it wouldn't work. I've seen some tutorials with python, but before changing my whole code i would like to know if it's also possible the way i've done it so far. here's the code for the fetch:

```
app.get("/ask", async (req, res) => {
  const standardPrompt = prompt;
  const question = req.query.q;

  try {
    const gpt3Response = await axios.post(
      "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions",
      {
        prompt: `${standardPrompt}: ${question}`,
        max_tokens: 500,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(gpt3Response.data);

    res.json(gpt3Response.data.choices[0].text.trim());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Error in processing request");
  }
});
```

would be great if anyone could help! Thanks.

Comment: So what **exactly** is the "error object"?

Comment: I use langchain with `const chat = new ChatOpenAI({ temperature: 0, modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo" });` and it works, so try that name of model.